# PHP union two array in one

Tags: php, arrays

who can kindly explain how to combine two arrays so as to generate a third that has all the fields of the first two?

```
//array1
$data: array =
0: array =
   Codice: string = AAA
   Descrizione: string = descrizione AAA
   Giacenza: string = 90
1: array =
   Codice: string = BBB
   Descrizione: string = descrizione BBB
   Giacenza: string = 9 
2: array =
   Codice: string = CCC
   Descrizione: string = descrizione CC
   Giacenza: string = 19

//array 2
$data1: array =
0: array =
    Codice: string = CCC
    Impegno: string = 10
1: array =
   Codice: string = AAA
   Impegno: string = 12
```

the result I want to get is

```
//array unito
$unito array =
0: array =
   Codice: string = AAA
   Descrizione: string = descrizione AAA
   Giacenza: string = 90
   Impegno: string = 10
1: array =
   Codice: string = BBB
   Descrizione: string = descrizione BBB
   Giacenza: string = 9
   Impegno: string = 0
2: array =
   Codice: string = CCC
   Descrizione: string = descrizione CC
   Giacenza: string = 19
   Impegno: string = 12`
```

Comment: The rules are not clear...there are keys that could get overwritten and the second element value `impegno` was set as the third element in the final array.

Comment: You want to combine those 2 arrays based on Codice key or what ?

Comment: I want to combine by Codice

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly you want something like this:

```
$data = [ 
    [
   'Codice' => 'AAA',
   'Descrizione' => 'descrizione AAA',
    'Giacenza' => 90,
     ],
    [
   'Codice' => 'BBB',
   'Descrizione' => 'descrizione BBB',
    'Giacenza' => 9,
     ],
    [
   'Codice' => 'CCC',
   'Descrizione' => 'descrizione CC',
    'Giacenza' => 19,
     ],
 ];

$data2 = [
    [
    'Codice' => 'CCC',
    'Impegno' => 10,
    ],
    [
     'Codice' => 'AAA',
     'Impegno' => 12,
    ],
         ];

$impegnoByCodice = array_combine(array_column($data2, 'Codice'),
                                 array_column($data2, 'Impegno'));


array_walk($data, function(&$item) use(&$impegnoByCodice) {
                      $item['Impegno'] = $impegnoByCodice[$item['Codice']] ?? 0;
                  }
           );

var_dump($data);
```

[Try it online](https://ideone.com/krpBII)

Comment: i want to show all records combine if in array $data there is not corrrispondece with $data1 i show $item['Impegno']=0 else $item['Impegno]=impegno array($data1)
is possible?

Comment: Have you tried my example online ? ("Impegno" field is 0 for element 'BBB')

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_reduce](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) function to create your union array like this:

```
$unito = array_reduce( $data, function ( $carry, $item ) use ($data1) {

    $key = codice_key($data1, $item['Codice']);
    if ( $key !== false ) {
        $carry[] = array_merge($item, $data1[$key]);
    } else {
        $carry[] = array_merge($item, [ 'Impegno' => 0 ]);
    }
    return $carry;

}, []);

// check if codice value exists in array and return its index or false otherwise
function codice_key($array, $value) {
    return array_search($value, array_column($array, 'Codice'));
}
```

I put [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/dfd1d83c823d1c80bd9e5248b34b537497db2a3e) a php sandbox to test code online

Comment: @MaxDG, Glad it helps, If my answer works for you, You can mark it as best answer, and vote up :°)